# I can't get proper time time difference between two times

Tags: php, datetime, time, strtotime

I have 2 times. `$delv_start` and `$delv_end`. I'm using the following code. It works fine if start date is in AM and ending date is in PM. The problem arises when both dates are in AM. Lets say that delivery starts at 8 AM and ends at 12 AM (at night), the restaurant status comes close. How will I counter that? Here is my code.

```
$delv_start = explode("_", $restaurant['delv_' . $day . '_from']);
$delv_end = explode("_", $restaurant['delv_' . $day . '_to']);

if ($delv_start[2] == 'am') {
     $delv_start[2] = 'AM';
} else if ($delv_start[2] == 'pm') {
    $delv_start[2] = 'PM';
}

if ($delv_end[2] == 'am') {
    $delv_end[2] = 'AM';
} else if ($delv_end[2] == 'pm') {
   $delv_end[2] = 'PM';
}

$open = sprintf('%02d', $delv_start[0]) . ':' . sprintf('%02d', $delv_start[1]) . ' ' . $delv_start[2];
$close = sprintf('%02d', $delv_end[0]) . ':' . sprintf('%02d', $delv_end[1]) . ' ' . $delv_end[2];

$time1 = strtotime($open);
$time2 = strtotime($close);

if ($time >= $time1 && $time <= $time2) {
     $status = 'Open';
     $color = 'green';
} else {
     $status = 'Close';
     $color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: please let me know your full format of time as example

Comment: `$delv_start = 8_0_am` and `$delv_end = 12_00_am`

Comment: actually you should use your complete date time format after that it would be efficience

Comment: But i can't change my whole structure now.